# Project Euler 8 program not providing correct answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem finding the correct answer to the problem.

I have the following code:

```
import time

print("This program will provide the largest product of 13 adjacent digits from a given number")

num = str(input("Enter the number from which you want to find the largest product"))

start = time.time()

biggest = 0

for i in range(len(num) - 12):
    a = int(num[i])
    b = int(num[i + 1])
    c = int(num[i + 2])
    d = int(num[i + 3])
    e = int(num[i + 4])
    f = int(num[i + 5])
    g = int(num[i + 6])
    h = int(num[i + 7])
    i = int(num[i + 8])
    j = int(num[i + 9])
    k = int(num[i + 10])
    l = int(num[i + 11])
    m = int(num[i + 12])
    product = a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h * i * j * k * l * m
    if product > biggest:
        biggest = product

print(biggest)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

I end up getting 823011840 which is the wrong answer, yet I do not know what is wrong with this program.

Comment: The numbers can be negative?

Answer (score 0):

One of the variables created in the inner loop has the same name `i`as the variable that controls the outer loop. That way variables `j`,`k`,`l`,`n` and `m` never get their intended value, but instead get `j = int(num[int(num[i + 8]) + 9])` etc.

What the loop essentially does is:

```
for outer_i in range(len(num) - 12):
    i = outer_i
    a = int(num[i])
    b = int(num[i + 1])
    c = int(num[i + 2])
    d = int(num[i + 3])
    e = int(num[i + 4])
    f = int(num[i + 5])
    g = int(num[i + 6])
    h = int(num[i + 7])
    inner_i = int(num[i + 8])
    i = inner_i
    j = int(num[i + 9])
    k = int(num[i + 10])
    l = int(num[i + 11])
    m = int(num[i + 12])
    product = a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h * i * j * k * l * m
    if product > biggest:
        biggest = product
```

Apart from using a different name for the outer variable, here is a suggestion for speed improvement using a sliding window approach:

- Split num into parts between zeros
- For each part 'num_part':

  - skip it if it has less than 13 elements
  - calculate p, the product of the first 13 elements
  - test p for maximality
  - for each t starting from 13:

    - divide p by num_part[t-13] and multiply by num_part[t]
    - test p for maximality

Comment: One-liner solution (if functools is imported): `print(max(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, map(int, data[i:i+13]), 1) for i in range(len(data) - 12)))`